If the zero set of the Fourier transform of a singular measure is empty , then the measue must be a Dirac measure?
Let $\mu$ be a Bore probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with compact support. Its Fourier transform is  defined as $$\hat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}d\mu(x).$$
We call the set $Z(\hat{\mu})=\{\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d:\hat{\mu}(\xi)=0\}$ the zero set of $\hat{\mu}(\xi)$.
It is well known that if $\mu=\delta_a$ is a Dirac measure at $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$, then $\hat{\mu}(\xi)=e^{-2\pi i a\cdot \xi}$ and hence $Z(\hat{\mu})=\emptyset.$
My question is the converse statement: if  $\mu$ is a singular (with respective the Lebesgue measure) Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with compact support and $Z(\hat{\mu})=\emptyset,$ then is it must a Dirac measure?
Any comments on it would be appreciated!

Can you do $d=1$?

@GEdgar Thanks. Wen $d=1$, the zero set is discrete. But it seems that this is no use for our problem. By the way, if we can show that $|\hat{\mu}(\xi)|\equiv 1$ then the measue must be a Dirac measure. Unfortunately, I have no idea for it. Would you like to give some comments on it.

Here is an attempt ...
$$
\mu = \frac{1}{3}(\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_\pi)
$$
a singular measure concentrated on three points.  The Fourier transform
$$
\hat\mu(y) = \frac{1}{3}\left(e^{-2i\pi y}+e^{-4i\pi y}+e^{-2\pi^2i y}\right)
$$
seems to have no real zeros...
$|\hat{\mu}(y)|$


Breaking news.  $\{1,2,5/2\}$ also yields no real zeros.  It is periodic, so proof should be easy!
$$
\mu = \frac{1}{3}(\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_{5/2})
$$
$|\hat{\mu}(y)|$


@GEdgar  Many thanks! Good examples. But it seems that it is not easy to prove it. Is the irrational number π
is essential? I mean if all the Dirac measures support on rational numbers, or even on integers, can we guarantee that the zero set is still empty?

@spaceisdarkgreen Many thanks!
